# LDAPs using Anonymous Access to AD forest

Tags: active-directory, iis, domain, ldap, domain-controller

There is a problem related to AD which I cannot understand what configuration is missing to fix the issue.

I have two DCs: testa and testb and both contain AD.

I'm logged in to testa and I'm trying to get all the domains in testb.

When I'm using LDAP, the following line works as expected using anonymous access to the DC testb :
DirectoryEntry trustedForest = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://tstb.local/RootDSE");

But when I'm using LDAPS, that is configuring the AuthenticationType to be AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer, I'm getting the following error:

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

If I supply the user name and password to the DirectroyEntry as following :

DirectoryEntry trustedForest = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://tstb.local/RootDSE",user,pass);

It works fine.

Is it possible using anonymous access while using LDAPS? I don't want the user to keep all the users and passwords of the DC in order to get the domains available in them.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous LDAP queries are usually disabled on Active Directory domain controllers, and for very good security reasons.

Any authenticated user can perform LDAP queries (as long as they are only reading non-sensitive data); the best approach is thus to create a generic user account for this purpose and use it whenever some application or device needs to query AD for information (f.e. network printers/scanners, firewalls, proxies, wireless access points...).

Comment: Do you mean that I need to impersonate to that generic user anytime I want to read the domains from the other forest? But how is it possible that the anonymous ldap does work when I'm using LDAP unsecured?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB LDAPS unlike LDAP requires you to have certificate on client's system. I imagine that if you are trying to use anonymous logon with LDAPS no cert is available/accessible (it's private certificate for user) -> LDAPS not working. Additionally what's the point of having secure connection with anonymous access?

Comment: @Yan Skursky You are correct. I do have certificate available. The point of having secure connection with anonymous access is to allow anyone to preform the ldap queries but keep the packets secured. I just wondered if its possible.

Comment: The point he's trying to make is that it's silly trying to keep those packets secured.  If anyone wanted them, they could just ask the DC directly!

Comment: You can do it, issue a certificate to be used by the application itself.